# Insert a dynamic vector into a matrix

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

If I have the following dynamic vector

```
   Cs[NN_] := 
 Table[{Sin[(2*i - 1) τ], Sin[(2*i - 1) τ]}, {i, 1, NN}]   // 
Flatten
```

The size of Cs depends on the integer NN. I want to construct a bigger matrix which has the following format:

```
Smat[NN_] := {{Cs[NN], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {0, Cs[NN], 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {0, 0, Cs[NN], 0, 0, 0},
          {0, 0, 0, Cs[NN], 0, 0},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, Cs[NN], 0},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Cs[NN]}}
```

Please note the size (number of rows and columns) of Smat depends on the size of Cs. How can I construct Smat automatically?

I appreciate your help in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
NN = 3;
n = 6;
Flatten /@ (IdentityMatrix[n] /. 1-> Cs[NN])
```

[image]

Comment: `NestList[RotateRight, PadRight[Cs[NN], 11], 5]`

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't want to specify "n". The size of Smat should be produced automatically.

Comment: @qahtah you can follow what cvgmt did and define it as a function argument to specify it only when you want. See for example what LouisB and I did and adopt the function defining with the approach suggested here

Answer (score 3):

This method uses `SparseArray` and `Band`

```
smat[nn_] := With[{c = Cs[nn]},
  SparseArray[Table[Band[{1, k}] -> c[[k]], {k, Length[c]}],
   {6,Length[c] + 5}]
  ]

smat[3]//MatrixForm
```

[image]

Use `Normal` to convert the sparse array to a list of lists, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to minimally modify your code using [**`Sequence`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) in a [**`ReplaceAll`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html).

```
Cs[NN_] := 
 Table[{Sin[(2*i - 1) τ], Sin[(2*i - 1) τ]}, {i, 1, NN}] // 
  Flatten
Smat[NN_] := {{Cs[NN], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, Cs[NN], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
     Cs[NN], 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, Cs[NN], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, Cs[NN], 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Cs[NN]}} /. Cs[NN] -> Sequence @@ Cs[NN]

Partition[MatrixForm /@ Table[Smat[xx], {xx, 2, 5}], 2]
```

> [image: grid]